# cloudfront spa subpath without s3 hosting

Tags: amazon-s3, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I have a SPA app in S3. Api in EC2

My cloudfront logic is as follows:

- / - api-origin
- /front/* - s3-bucket-origin

The front has its ways, for example

- example.com/front/User/Login
- example.com/front/Documents/
- example.com/front/UserSetting/

I managed to launch the application through s3 bucket hosting proxy. But I want to try to implement this without s3 hosting enabled.

What did I try:

Added cloudfront function for front behavior.

```
function handler(event) {
 var request = event.request;
 request.uri = request.uri.replace(/^\/[^/]*\//, "/");
 request.uri += '/front/index.html';

return request;
```

}

But I get 404

Please tell me how to implement this correctly. Preferably without Lambda (only cloudfront functions)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for myself. I don't know how correct this is, but it works.

```
function handler(event) {
  var request = event.request;
  
  request.uri = request.uri.replace(/^\/[^/]*\//, "/");
  
  if (!request.uri.includes('.')) {
    request.uri = "/index.html";
  }

  return request;
}
```

I hope cloudfront functions don't cost a lot of money